# Blog advertising solicitation

Tags: discussion, blog

The blog email account has received a couple emails.  I assume SE isn't interested and I was going to send a polite no thank you email.  Does someone from the community team want to deal with this?  Should we ignore it?

---

Hello,

I was thrilled when I came across your site today. It looks like you put a lot of passion into creating a reliable source of information for visitors.

This is a great opportunity to be compensated for all of the effort you have put into your site. I have a client who is also impressed by your website. We would like to discuss the possibility of adding relevant information to your site.

I would love to send you more details about my client and your compensation. I look forward to hearing from you soon.

Thank you for your time,

-- 
Denise Richard
Content Advocate
Internetreach

---

Hello,

I sent you an email a few days ago... Just checking in to see if you wanted to know more about the offer. This is a legitimate opportunity to make some extra money each month from your website.

At the very least, I'd like to provide you with the details so that you can be fully informed when coming to a decision about placing a resource to my client on your site.

Please let me know if you would like to hear the details about this opportunity, I am happy to explain everything.

Thank you very much for your time,

-- 
Denise Richard
Content Advocate
Internetreach

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would consider these as spam and just delete them.

Comment: I concur; these are effectively spam.